# Angular2 and InstaFeed query

Tags: javascript, angular, instafeedjs

im making a site for a client, which requires their Instagram photos to be shown on one of the tabs. Im using Angular4, and Instafeed to accomplish this. I installed Instafeed using NPM, linked the script in .angular-cli, the css in the .angular-cli as well, followed by the instaFeed script on the Tab's HTML and finally ending with a Div of class InstaFeed. However, on running the site, I do not see any errors, but no pictures are being displayed either. Any help please??

Answer (score 4):

This maybe late for the op but right on time for someone else struggling with this. If you have the scripts declared in angular cli, what worked for me is to declare the instafeed variable inside the component you aim to use instafeed like so...

```
declare var Instafeed:any;
```

Then inside this same component add the code for instafeed

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: 'xxxxxx',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /><p>Likes {{likes}}</p><p>Comments {{comments}}</p></a>',
    limit: 1
});
feed.run();
```